# php header() Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, header

Can anyone tell me why this authentication won't work?

This is a breakdown:

1) I'm trying to create a simple authentication using WWW-Authenticate with the php header() function.
2) When I go to the page, the authentication box pops up like so:
[image: I receive this prompt when the page is loaded.] 
3) If I remove the script (see script below), the page loads as expected.
4) No matter what password I put in or add/remove the Realm, Stale etc, nothing bites and the Authentication box just keeps looping when I click "Log In".

```
if( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != NULL && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != NULL && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == ‘admin1’ && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == ‘pwd1’ ) {
   $_SESSION['login_flag'] = true;
  } else {
header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\”Schoolroom\”, stale=FALSE");
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    print "<h1>401 Unauthorized</h1>";
    exit();
  }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I've also tried in multiple browsers and various computers, same issue.

**UPDATE: 10:44am PST, July 5 - This is where I am at so far with modified, updated and commented code:**

```
 <?php
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Secret page"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

// Status flag:
$LoginSuccessful = false;

// Check username and password:
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){

$Username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$Password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

if ($Username == 'usrnm' && $Password == 'pswrd') {
$LoginSuccessful = true;
}
}

// Login passed successful?
if (!$LoginSuccessful){

/*
** The user gets here if:
**
** 1. The user entered incorrect login data (three times)
** --> User will see the error message from below
**
** 2. Or the user requested the page for the first time
** --> Then the 401 headers apply and the "login box" will
** be shown
*/

// The text inside the realm section will be visible for the
// user in the login box
//header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Secret page"');
//header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

print "Login failed!\n";

}
else {

// The user entered the correct login data, put
// your confidential data in here:

print 'you reached the secret page!';
}

?>
```

However, the script **does not** prompt to login window but instead renders "Login Failed".

We tested it with all available PHP versions 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, but to no avail.

Comment: Is there any error output?

Comment: Hi JohnZ, no, there is no error, only what is displayed on the prompt.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to use this method rather than just a standard form?

Comment: Difster, because there is an app I am trying to resolve as-is without having to redo something another way. Trying to prevent a domino effect if I can keep the entire code in tact. And honestly, would like to know why this code doesn't work when it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're testing to see if `$_SESSION['login_flag']` is set and also true.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_flag'] && $_SESSION['login_flag'] == true)) { 
//load the page without authentication
}
else {
//ask for authentication
}
```

Comment: Difster, thanks for the suggestion. Well, I implemented this, but now I am logging in automatically, no matter the device or connection point, so it appears the Auth is not working and prompting:  if(isset($_SESSION['login_flag']) && $_SESSION['login_flag'] == true) { 
      if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != NULL && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != NULL && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'admin1' && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'pwd1' );
   else {...

Comment: Please update your original post with the new code. It will be easier to evaluate.

Comment: Difster, I updated the code of the original request.